# How does one detect and deter golden SAML attacks?

Tags: attacks, defense, detection, saml

How does one defend, detect and deter golden SAML attacks?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242146/solarwinds-orion-saml-compromise-mass-cert-update

Answer (score 1):

Several methods could be used to detect'em:

1. Correlating service provider login events with corresponding authentication events in ADFS and Domain Controllers
2. Identifying certificate export events in Active Directory Federation Services
3. Customizing SAML response to identify irregular access
4. Detecting malicious Ative Directory Federation Services trust
   modification

Those methods are well documented [here](https://www.sygnia.co/golden-saml-advisory)

And for mitigation, the best you could do is following best practice guides and recommendations, Microsoft provides [an excellent resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/best-practices-securing-ad-fs) for doing this.

FireEye published a well-detailed paper on the attack and provides some extra guidance on ADFS attack mitigation: [Remediation and Hardening Strategies for Microsoft 365 to Defend Against UNC2452](https://www.fireeye.com/content/dam/fireeye-www/blog/pdfs/wp-m-unc2452-2021-000343-01.pdf)

If not using ADFS [this](https://www.riskinsight-wavestone.com/en/2018/05/golden-saml-attack/) should help.